# Running a symlink locally

Tags: linux, bash, rsync, symbolic-link

I am running the same program multiple times over a linux platform. It is compiled at another server, and frequently updated, and it's uploaded over through rsync to all "hosting" servers, which do not have compilation software.

The thing is, I want to keep all programs updated as much as possible. What I thought of first would be to have several copies of the program (it's an executable, in C++) installed and configured, but the executable was a symlink to a copy of it that was being rsync'd.

So, I have a symlink pointing to a file that is being synchronized with the compilation server.

The problem is that when running the symlink it's almost as if I had run it on the other folder (the one where the executable is stored) manually: it's not loading the configuration files, at all, because it's attempting to find them at the executable's location instead of the location where the symlinks are.

I run 8 copies of it on each VPS, and currently run 5 VPSes. Manually updating each executable (even with a bash script) would be impossible. The "program" needs to be updated seamlessly whenever a user wants to restart his.

I thought about running it with a bash script that would first copy the file over before running it, but would there be any way around it using symlinks, that would still allow updates to flow in?

Thanks!

Comment: Does rsync copy ensure the binary image is not being replaced whilst it is being executed?

Comment: Pass the location of the config files as a parameter to the program, or set the location in an environment variable that the program reads.

Comment: Unfortunately parsing the config files as parameters directly to the program is impossible because there are 8 copies of it running on each VPS, all requiring different config files.

Rsync doesn't ensure that, but since I was able to delete files that were being symlinked while they were running, I guess that's not an issue.

Comment: Then pass the path of the directory holding the config files, or use an environmental variable similarly.

Comment: Then the method of updating is not safe. A binary image could be modified whilst it is being loaded into memory.

Comment: I guess I'll have to go with manual updates then or a bash script to be run on every execution. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Nuno what happens if you `cd` into the directory containing the config and then run the program? e.g., `cd /configpath && /somepath/symlink.bin`

Comment: @Nuno read your question again. It sounds like the program uses something like `readlink` to get the real path even if referenced through a symlink. This could be tricky to resolve. Could you symlink config files etc. into the location of the real file?

Comment: I have fixed the problem by replacing symlinks with a rsync run on a cron, that updates each individual binary.